# how to know what is the mount folder that generate STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE or STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD?

Tags: mount, cifs

We have a linux red hat 7.9 server with a lot of user that mount folders.

during the mount there are asked for their account password (to access the network folder that is source of the mount).

but when the password used is no more valid (password are often modified) then we have a lot of error messages in /var/log/messages :

```
Feb 28 18:45:06 TOTO kernel: cifs_vfs_err: 63 callbacks suppressed
Feb 28 18:45:06 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = xxxxxxxxxxx
Feb 28 18:45:06 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Feb 28 18:45:06 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Feb 28 18:45:06 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = xxxxxxxxxxx
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = xxxxxxxxxxx
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = xxxxxxxxxxx
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = xxxxxxxxxxx
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: CIFS VFS: Free previous auth_key.response = xxxxxxxxxxx
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:07 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:08 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:08 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:08 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
Feb 28 18:45:08 TOTO kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006a STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
```

using mount command or findmnt I can have the list of all mount but I can't see which one is generating the error message. And it is also painfull to ask all user to check if their mount are still valid...

is there a way to check the statut of all mount to detect which one is not working correctly ?

Comment: `/etc/mtab` is the system-generated (and up-to-date) list of all the mounted filesystems. The failed mount is NOT in this list.

Comment: thanks, then I need to make a "diff" between mount that are listed in /etc/mtab and another list ? which one ? mount output ? findmnt output ? 
please note that the failing mount has been successful at the time it was created, it failed once the password is modified.